# show that the function $ \ kf \ $ defined by $ \ kf(x)=k(f(x)) \ \forall \ x \in [a,b] \ $ also satisfies Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

If $ \ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be a function that satisfies Intermediate Value Theorem, then show that the function $ \ kf \ $ defined by $ \ kf(x)=k(f(x)) \ \forall \ x \in [a,b] \ $ also satisfies Intermediate Value Theorem.

**Answer:**

Since $ \ f \ $ satisfies Intermediate value theorem for $ \ l \in [f(a),f(b)] \ $ there exists $ \ c \in (a,b) \ $ such that $ f(c)=l \ $

If $ \ k=0 \ $ , then $ \ kf(x)=0f(x)=0 \ $ satisfies IVT trivially.

But how to do the case when $ \ k \neq 0 \ $ ?

Please help me.

Comment: Did you copy your math correctly? Is it $kf(x)=kx$, which doesn't require knowing that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value theorem, or is it $(kf)(x)=k\cdot f(x)$, which does?

Comment: Yes it is my mistake . $ kf(x)=k \cdot f(x) \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k\ne 0 $ let $g(x)=kf(x)$, then if $l \in (g(a),g(b))$, we have $l/k \in (f(a),f(b)).$

Therefore, we have $f(c)=l/k$ which implies  $l=kf(c)=g(c) \in ( g(a),g(b))$